# Local document is different from hosted one for math formulas

Tags: read-the-docs

I have my documents for read-the-docs in a github repository. Before pushing to the repo, I always run sphinx locally to produce the html. When I am satisfied I push my changes to the github repo and read-the-docs builds the documentation.

In a most recent change I have used a lot of math. My document looks fine produced locally, but the build by read-the-docs looks different especially for formatting the tabulators `&`.

Is there a way to produce the document in the same way as read-the-docs does it in order to avoid such surprises?

Thanks for any help.

Helmut

Comment: You need to provide more information for us to help. What does the RTD build log show? Any warnings or errors? Did you configure RTD to install your project's requirements?

Comment: The build log shows some latex errors during the build of the pdf. It is not my problem to fix them. My problem is: How can I see the problems locally on my machine? The problem solving cycle by pushing to the repo and waiting for the build is far too long to discover such kind of errors.

Comment: Are you problems on the PDF or HTML output?